# Construct nested hierarchy based on flat data

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, flatten

Given two unordered flat arrays:

```
teamLinks {
  parentBpxTeamId,
  childBpxTeamId
}

teams {
  bpxId,
  ...
}
```

I would like to restructure teams into nested hierarchies (arbitrary amount of levels) based on `teamLinks` and I'm struggling to think of a working (and hopefully efficient) way of doing this.

So the data should end up like this:

```
[
  {
    bpxId: 1,
    children: [
      {
        bpxId: 2,
        children: [
          {
            bpxId: 3,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If `teamLinks` was:

```
[
  {
    parentBpxTeamId: 1,
    childBpxTeamId: 2,
  },
  {
    parentBpxTeamId: 2,
    childBpxTeamId: 3,
  }
]
```

```js
const teams=[{bpxId:1},{bpxId:2},{bpxId:3},{bpxId:4},{bpxId:5},{bpxId:6},{bpxId:7},{bpxId:8},{bpxId:9},{bpxId:10},{bpxId:11},{bpxId:12},{bpxId:13},{bpxId:14},{bpxId:15},{bpxId:16},{bpxId:17},{bpxId:18},{bpxId:19},{bpxId:20},{bpxId:21},{bpxId:22},{bpxId:23},{bpxId:24},{bpxId:25},{bpxId:26},{bpxId:27},{bpxId:28},{bpxId:29},{bpxId:30},{bpxId:31},{bpxId:32},{bpxId:33},{bpxId:34},{bpxId:35},{bpxId:36},{bpxId:37},{bpxId:38},{bpxId:39},{bpxId:40},{bpxId:41},{bpxId:42},{bpxId:43},{bpxId:44},{bpxId:45},{bpxId:46},{bpxId:47},{bpxId:48},{bpxId:49},{bpxId:50},{bpxId:51},{bpxId:52},{bpxId:53},{bpxId:54},{bpxId:55},{bpxId:56},{bpxId:57},{bpxId:58},{bpxId:59},{bpxId:60},{bpxId:61},{bpxId:62},{bpxId:63},{bpxId:64},{bpxId:65},{bpxId:66},{bpxId:67},{bpxId:68},{bpxId:69},{bpxId:70},{bpxId:71},{bpxId:72},{bpxId:73},{bpxId:74},{bpxId:75},{bpxId:76},{bpxId:77},{bpxId:78},{bpxId:79},{bpxId:80},{bpxId:81},{bpxId:82},{bpxId:83},{bpxId:84},{bpxId:85},{bpxId:86},{bpxId:87},{bpxId:88},{bpxId:89},{bpxId:90},{bpxId:91},{bpxId:92},{bpxId:93},{bpxId:94},{bpxId:95},{bpxId:96},{bpxId:97},{bpxId:98},{bpxId:99},{bpxId:100},{bpxId:101},{bpxId:102},{bpxId:103},{bpxId:104},{bpxId:105},{bpxId:106},{bpxId:107},{bpxId:108},{bpxId:109},{bpxId:110},{bpxId:111},{bpxId:112},{bpxId:113},{bpxId:114},{bpxId:115},{bpxId:116},{bpxId:117},{bpxId:118},{bpxId:119},{bpxId:120},{bpxId:121},{bpxId:122},{bpxId:123},{bpxId:124},{bpxId:125},{bpxId:126},{bpxId:127},{bpxId:128},{bpxId:129},{bpxId:130},{bpxId:131},{bpxId:132},{bpxId:133},{bpxId:134},{bpxId:135},{bpxId:136},{bpxId:137},{bpxId:138},{bpxId:139},{bpxId:140},{bpxId:141},{bpxId:142},{bpxId:143},{bpxId:144},{bpxId:145},{bpxId:146},{bpxId:147},{bpxId:148},{bpxId:149},{bpxId:150},{bpxId:151},{bpxId:152},{bpxId:153},{bpxId:154},{bpxId:155},{bpxId:156},{bpxId:157},{bpxId:158},{bpxId:159},{bpxId:160},{bpxId:161},{bpxId:162},{bpxId:163},{bpxId:164},{bpxId:165},{bpxId:166},{bpxId:167},{bpxId:168},{bpxId:169},{bpxId:170},{bpxId:171},{bpxId:172},{bpxId:173},{bpxId:174},{bpxId:175},{bpxId:176},{bpxId:177},{bpxId:178},{bpxId:179},{bpxId:180},{bpxId:181},{bpxId:182},{bpxId:183},{bpxId:184},{bpxId:185},{bpxId:186},{bpxId:187},{bpxId:188},{bpxId:189},{bpxId:190},{bpxId:191},{bpxId:192},{bpxId:193},{bpxId:194},{bpxId:195},{bpxId:196},{bpxId:197},{bpxId:198},{bpxId:199},{bpxId:200},{bpxId:201},{bpxId:202},{bpxId:203},{bpxId:204},{bpxId:205},{bpxId:206},{bpxId:207},{bpxId:208},{bpxId:209},{bpxId:210},{bpxId:211},{bpxId:212},{bpxId:213},{bpxId:214},{bpxId:215},{bpxId:216},{bpxId:217},{bpxId:218},{bpxId:219},{bpxId:220},{bpxId:221},{bpxId:222},{bpxId:223},{bpxId:224},{bpxId:225},{bpxId:226},{bpxId:227},{bpxId:228},{bpxId:229},{bpxId:230},{bpxId:231},{bpxId:232},{bpxId:233},{bpxId:234},{bpxId:235},{bpxId:236},{bpxId:237},{bpxId:238},{bpxId:239},{bpxId:240},{bpxId:241},{bpxId:242},{bpxId:243},{bpxId:244},{bpxId:245},{bpxId:246},{bpxId:247},{bpxId:248},{bpxId:249},{bpxId:250},{bpxId:251},{bpxId:252},{bpxId:253},{bpxId:254},{bpxId:255},{bpxId:256},{bpxId:257},{bpxId:258},{bpxId:259},{bpxId:260},{bpxId:261},{bpxId:262},{bpxId:263},{bpxId:264},{bpxId:265},{bpxId:266},{bpxId:267},{bpxId:268},{bpxId:269},{bpxId:270},{bpxId:271},{bpxId:272},{bpxId:273},{bpxId:274},{bpxId:275},{bpxId:276},{bpxId:277},{bpxId:278},{bpxId:279},{bpxId:280},{bpxId:281},{bpxId:282},{bpxId:283},{bpxId:284},{bpxId:285},{bpxId:286},{bpxId:287},{bpxId:288},{bpxId:289},{bpxId:290},{bpxId:291},{bpxId:292},{bpxId:293},{bpxId:294},{bpxId:295},{bpxId:296},{bpxId:297},{bpxId:298},{bpxId:299},{bpxId:300},{bpxId:301},{bpxId:302},{bpxId:303},{bpxId:304},{bpxId:305},{bpxId:306},{bpxId:307},{bpxId:308},{bpxId:309},{bpxId:310},{bpxId:311},{bpxId:312},{bpxId:313},{bpxId:314},{bpxId:315},{bpxId:316},{bpxId:317},{bpxId:318},{bpxId:319},{bpxId:320},{bpxId:321},{bpxId:322},{bpxId:323},{bpxId:324},{bpxId:325},{bpxId:326},{bpxId:327},{bpxId:328},{bpxId:329},{bpxId:330},{bpxId:331},{bpxId:332},{bpxId:333},{bpxId:334},{bpxId:335},{bpxId:336},{bpxId:337},{bpxId:338},{bpxId:339},{bpxId:340},{bpxId:341},{bpxId:342},{bpxId:343},{bpxId:344},{bpxId:345},{bpxId:346},{bpxId:347},{bpxId:348},{bpxId:349},{bpxId:350},{bpxId:351},{bpxId:352},{bpxId:353},{bpxId:736},{bpxId:737},{bpxId:738},{bpxId:739},{bpxId:740},{bpxId:741},{bpxId:742},{bpxId:743},{bpxId:744},{bpxId:745},{bpxId:746},{bpxId:748},{bpxId:749},{bpxId:750},{bpxId:751},{bpxId:752},{bpxId:753},{bpxId:754},{bpxId:755},{bpxId:770},{bpxId:788},{bpxId:790},{bpxId:780},{bpxId:785},{bpxId:781},{bpxId:782},{bpxId:783},{bpxId:787},{bpxId:766},{bpxId:762},{bpxId:769},{bpxId:778},{bpxId:761},{bpxId:792},{bpxId:789},{bpxId:735},{bpxId:764},{bpxId:791},{bpxId:763},{bpxId:771},{bpxId:767},{bpxId:784},{bpxId:768},{bpxId:747},{bpxId:786},{bpxId:779},{bpxId:833}];

const teamLinks=[{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:2},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:11},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:91},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:270},{parentBpxTeamId:2,childBpxTeamId:3},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:4},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:5},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:6},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:7},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:8},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:9},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:10},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:92},{parentBpxTeamId:11,childBpxTeamId:12},{parentBpxTeamId:12,childBpxTeamId:13},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:15},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:24},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:38},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:54},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:62},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:69},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:73},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:76},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:88},{parentBpxTeamId:15,childBpxTeamId:16},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:17},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:18},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:19},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:20},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:21},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:22},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:23},{parentBpxTeamId:24,childBpxTeamId:25},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:26},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:27},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:28},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:29},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:30},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:31},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:32},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:33},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:34},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:35},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:36},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:37},{parentBpxTeamId:38,childBpxTeamId:39},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:40},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:41},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:42},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:43},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:44},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:45},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:46},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:47},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:48},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:49},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:50},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:51},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:52},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:53},{parentBpxTeamId:54,childBpxTeamId:55},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:56},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:57},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:58},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:59},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:60},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:61},{parentBpxTeamId:62,childBpxTeamId:63},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:64},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:65},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:66},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:67},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:68},{parentBpxTeamId:69,childBpxTeamId:70},{parentBpxTeamId:69,childBpxTeamId:71},{parentBpxTeamId:71,childBpxTeamId:72},{parentBpxTeamId:73,childBpxTeamId:74},{parentBpxTeamId:74,childBpxTeamId:75},{parentBpxTeamId:76,childBpxTeamId:77},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:78},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:79},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:80},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:81},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:82},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:83},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:84},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:85},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:86},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:87},{parentBpxTeamId:88,childBpxTeamId:89},{parentBpxTeamId:89,childBpxTeamId:90},{parentBpxTeamId:91,childBpxTeamId:3},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:94},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:97},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:100},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:103},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:104},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:106},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:109},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:112},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:115},{parentBpxTeamId:94,childBpxTeamId:95},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:96},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:98},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:99},{parentBpxTeamId:97,childBpxTeamId:95},{parentBpxTeamId:100,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:101,childBpxTeamId:102},{parentBpxTeamId:101,childBpxTeamId:105},{parentBpxTeamId:103,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:104,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:106,childBpxTeamId:107},{parentBpxTeamId:107,childBpxTeamId:108},{parentBpxTeamId:109,childBpxTeamId:110},{parentBpxTeamId:110,childBpxTeamId:111},{parentBpxTeamId:112,childBpxTeamId:113},{parentBpxTeamId:113,childBpxTeamId:114},{parentBpxTeamId:115,childBpxTeamId:116},{parentBpxTeamId:116,childBpxTeamId:117},{parentBpxTeamId:118,childBpxTeamId:119},{parentBpxTeamId:119,childBpxTeamId:120},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:122},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:139},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:144},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:123},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:125},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:127},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:129},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:131},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:133},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:135},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:137},{parentBpxTeamId:123,childBpxTeamId:124},{parentBpxTeamId:125,childBpxTeamId:126},{parentBpxTeamId:127,childBpxTeamId:128},{parentBpxTeamId:129,childBpxTeamId:130},{parentBpxTeamId:131,childBpxTeamId:132},{parentBpxTeamId:133,childBpxTeamId:134},{parentBpxTeamId:135,childBpxTeamId:136},{parentBpxTeamId:137,childBpxTeamId:138},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:140},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:141},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:142},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:143},{parentBpxTeamId:144,childBpxTeamId:145},{parentBpxTeamId:144,childBpxTeamId:146},{parentBpxTeamId:147,childBpxTeamId:148},{parentBpxTeamId:149,childBpxTeamId:150},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:154},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:156},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:158},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:160},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:162},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:164},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:166},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:168},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:170},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:172},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:174},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:153},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:155},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:157},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:159},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:161},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:163},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:165},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:167},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:169},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:171},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:173},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:175},{parentBpxTeamId:154,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:156,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:158,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:160,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:162,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:164,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:166,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:168,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:170,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:172,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:174,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:176,childBpxTeamId:177},{parentBpxTeamId:177,childBpxTeamId:178},{parentBpxTeamId:177,childBpxTeamId:768},{parentBpxTeamId:178,childBpxTeamId:179},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:181},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:183},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:185},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:187},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:189},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:191},{parentBpxTeamId:181,childBpxTeamId:182},{parentBpxTeamId:183,childBpxTeamId:184},{parentBpxTeamId:185,childBpxTeamId:186},{parentBpxTeamId:187,childBpxTeamId:188},{parentBpxTeamId:189,childBpxTeamId:190},{parentBpxTeamId:191,childBpxTeamId:192},{parentBpxTeamId:193,childBpxTeamId:194},{parentBpxTeamId:193,childBpxTeamId:197},{parentBpxTeamId:194,childBpxTeamId:195},{parentBpxTeamId:195,childBpxTeamId:196},{parentBpxTeamId:197,childBpxTeamId:198},{parentBpxTeamId:198,childBpxTeamId:199},{parentBpxTeamId:200,childBpxTeamId:201},{parentBpxTeamId:200,childBpxTeamId:204},{parentBpxTeamId:201,childBpxTeamId:202},{parentBpxTeamId:202,childBpxTeamId:203},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:205},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:207},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:209},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:210},{parentBpxTeamId:205,childBpxTeamId:206},{parentBpxTeamId:207,childBpxTeamId:208},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:212},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:215},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:217},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:219},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:221},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:223},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:226},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:228},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:230},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:232},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:234},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:236},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:238},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:240},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:242},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:244},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:246},{parentBpxTeamId:212,childBpxTeamId:213},{parentBpxTeamId:213,childBpxTeamId:214},{parentBpxTeamId:215,childBpxTeamId:216},{parentBpxTeamId:217,childBpxTeamId:218},{parentBpxTeamId:219,childBpxTeamId:220},{parentBpxTeamId:221,childBpxTeamId:222},{parentBpxTeamId:223,childBpxTeamId:224},{parentBpxTeamId:223,childBpxTeamId:225},{parentBpxTeamId:226,childBpxTeamId:227},{parentBpxTeamId:228,childBpxTeamId:229},{parentBpxTeamId:230,childBpxTeamId:231},{parentBpxTeamId:232,childBpxTeamId:233},{parentBpxTeamId:234,childBpxTeamId:235},{parentBpxTeamId:236,childBpxTeamId:237},{parentBpxTeamId:238,childBpxTeamId:239},{parentBpxTeamId:240,childBpxTeamId:241},{parentBpxTeamId:242,childBpxTeamId:243},{parentBpxTeamId:244,childBpxTeamId:245},{parentBpxTeamId:246,childBpxTeamId:247},{parentBpxTeamId:248,childBpxTeamId:249},{parentBpxTeamId:249,childBpxTeamId:250},{parentBpxTeamId:249,childBpxTeamId:251},{parentBpxTeamId:252,childBpxTeamId:253},{parentBpxTeamId:253,childBpxTeamId:254},{parentBpxTeamId:255,childBpxTeamId:256},{parentBpxTeamId:255,childBpxTeamId:257},{parentBpxTeamId:263,childBpxTeamId:264},{parentBpxTeamId:264,childBpxTeamId:265},{parentBpxTeamId:266,childBpxTeamId:267},{parentBpxTeamId:267,childBpxTeamId:268},{parentBpxTeamId:270,childBpxTeamId:271},{parentBpxTeamId:271,childBpxTeamId:272},{parentBpxTeamId:273,childBpxTeamId:274},{parentBpxTeamId:274,childBpxTeamId:275},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:276},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:277},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:278},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:279},{parentBpxTeamId:280,childBpxTeamId:281},{parentBpxTeamId:281,childBpxTeamId:282},{parentBpxTeamId:283,childBpxTeamId:284},{parentBpxTeamId:284,childBpxTeamId:285},{parentBpxTeamId:286,childBpxTeamId:287},{parentBpxTeamId:287,childBpxTeamId:288},{parentBpxTeamId:289,childBpxTeamId:290},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:291},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:292},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:293},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:294},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:295},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:296},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:297},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:298},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:299},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:300},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:301},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:302},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:303},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:304},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:305},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:306},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:307},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:308},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:309},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:310},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:311},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:312},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:313},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:314},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:315},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:316},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:317},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:318},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:319},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:320},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:321},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:322},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:323},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:324},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:325},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:326},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:327},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:328},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:329},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:330},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:331},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:332},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:333},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:334},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:335},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:336},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:337},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:338},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:339},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:340},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:341},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:342},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:343},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:344},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:345},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:346},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:347},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:348},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:349},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:350},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:351},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:352},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:353},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:736},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:737},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:738},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:739},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:740},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:741},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:742},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:743},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:744},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:745},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:746},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:766},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:748},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:749},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:750},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:751},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:752},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:753},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:754},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:755},{parentBpxTeamId:761,childBpxTeamId:762},{parentBpxTeamId:762,childBpxTeamId:763},{parentBpxTeamId:762,childBpxTeamId:764},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:747},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:778},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:789},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:769},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:770},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:771},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:779},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:780},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:781},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:782},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:783},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:784},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:785},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:786},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:787},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:788},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:790},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:791},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:792}];
```

I'd show what I have so far, but I haven't got anything working yet! Will update if I do. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet should work:

```
//                                        [key       , value                    ]
const parents = new Map(teams.map(team => [team.bpxId, { ...team, children: [] }]));
const lut = new Map(parents);

teamLinks.forEach(({ parentBpxTeamId, childBpxTeamId }) => {
  lut.get(parentBpxTeamId).children.push(lut.get(childBpxTeamId));
  parents.delete(childBpxTeamId);
});

const hierarchies = Array.from(parents.values());
```

It creates a map of parent team hierarchies and a lookup table, both using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to reference each team hierarchy based on its id, then loops through each link and appends each child reference to each parent reference. This approach assumes there are no duplicate links in the `teamLinks` array.

Borrowing from Nina's answer, this also removes children from the top level of the hierarchy when they are added under other teams.

```js
const teams=[{bpxId:1},{bpxId:2},{bpxId:3},{bpxId:4},{bpxId:5},{bpxId:6},{bpxId:7},{bpxId:8},{bpxId:9},{bpxId:10},{bpxId:11},{bpxId:12},{bpxId:13},{bpxId:14},{bpxId:15},{bpxId:16},{bpxId:17},{bpxId:18},{bpxId:19},{bpxId:20},{bpxId:21},{bpxId:22},{bpxId:23},{bpxId:24},{bpxId:25},{bpxId:26},{bpxId:27},{bpxId:28},{bpxId:29},{bpxId:30},{bpxId:31},{bpxId:32},{bpxId:33},{bpxId:34},{bpxId:35},{bpxId:36},{bpxId:37},{bpxId:38},{bpxId:39},{bpxId:40},{bpxId:41},{bpxId:42},{bpxId:43},{bpxId:44},{bpxId:45},{bpxId:46},{bpxId:47},{bpxId:48},{bpxId:49},{bpxId:50},{bpxId:51},{bpxId:52},{bpxId:53},{bpxId:54},{bpxId:55},{bpxId:56},{bpxId:57},{bpxId:58},{bpxId:59},{bpxId:60},{bpxId:61},{bpxId:62},{bpxId:63},{bpxId:64},{bpxId:65},{bpxId:66},{bpxId:67},{bpxId:68},{bpxId:69},{bpxId:70},{bpxId:71},{bpxId:72},{bpxId:73},{bpxId:74},{bpxId:75},{bpxId:76},{bpxId:77},{bpxId:78},{bpxId:79},{bpxId:80},{bpxId:81},{bpxId:82},{bpxId:83},{bpxId:84},{bpxId:85},{bpxId:86},{bpxId:87},{bpxId:88},{bpxId:89},{bpxId:90},{bpxId:91},{bpxId:92},{bpxId:93},{bpxId:94},{bpxId:95},{bpxId:96},{bpxId:97},{bpxId:98},{bpxId:99},{bpxId:100},{bpxId:101},{bpxId:102},{bpxId:103},{bpxId:104},{bpxId:105},{bpxId:106},{bpxId:107},{bpxId:108},{bpxId:109},{bpxId:110},{bpxId:111},{bpxId:112},{bpxId:113},{bpxId:114},{bpxId:115},{bpxId:116},{bpxId:117},{bpxId:118},{bpxId:119},{bpxId:120},{bpxId:121},{bpxId:122},{bpxId:123},{bpxId:124},{bpxId:125},{bpxId:126},{bpxId:127},{bpxId:128},{bpxId:129},{bpxId:130},{bpxId:131},{bpxId:132},{bpxId:133},{bpxId:134},{bpxId:135},{bpxId:136},{bpxId:137},{bpxId:138},{bpxId:139},{bpxId:140},{bpxId:141},{bpxId:142},{bpxId:143},{bpxId:144},{bpxId:145},{bpxId:146},{bpxId:147},{bpxId:148},{bpxId:149},{bpxId:150},{bpxId:151},{bpxId:152},{bpxId:153},{bpxId:154},{bpxId:155},{bpxId:156},{bpxId:157},{bpxId:158},{bpxId:159},{bpxId:160},{bpxId:161},{bpxId:162},{bpxId:163},{bpxId:164},{bpxId:165},{bpxId:166},{bpxId:167},{bpxId:168},{bpxId:169},{bpxId:170},{bpxId:171},{bpxId:172},{bpxId:173},{bpxId:174},{bpxId:175},{bpxId:176},{bpxId:177},{bpxId:178},{bpxId:179},{bpxId:180},{bpxId:181},{bpxId:182},{bpxId:183},{bpxId:184},{bpxId:185},{bpxId:186},{bpxId:187},{bpxId:188},{bpxId:189},{bpxId:190},{bpxId:191},{bpxId:192},{bpxId:193},{bpxId:194},{bpxId:195},{bpxId:196},{bpxId:197},{bpxId:198},{bpxId:199},{bpxId:200},{bpxId:201},{bpxId:202},{bpxId:203},{bpxId:204},{bpxId:205},{bpxId:206},{bpxId:207},{bpxId:208},{bpxId:209},{bpxId:210},{bpxId:211},{bpxId:212},{bpxId:213},{bpxId:214},{bpxId:215},{bpxId:216},{bpxId:217},{bpxId:218},{bpxId:219},{bpxId:220},{bpxId:221},{bpxId:222},{bpxId:223},{bpxId:224},{bpxId:225},{bpxId:226},{bpxId:227},{bpxId:228},{bpxId:229},{bpxId:230},{bpxId:231},{bpxId:232},{bpxId:233},{bpxId:234},{bpxId:235},{bpxId:236},{bpxId:237},{bpxId:238},{bpxId:239},{bpxId:240},{bpxId:241},{bpxId:242},{bpxId:243},{bpxId:244},{bpxId:245},{bpxId:246},{bpxId:247},{bpxId:248},{bpxId:249},{bpxId:250},{bpxId:251},{bpxId:252},{bpxId:253},{bpxId:254},{bpxId:255},{bpxId:256},{bpxId:257},{bpxId:258},{bpxId:259},{bpxId:260},{bpxId:261},{bpxId:262},{bpxId:263},{bpxId:264},{bpxId:265},{bpxId:266},{bpxId:267},{bpxId:268},{bpxId:269},{bpxId:270},{bpxId:271},{bpxId:272},{bpxId:273},{bpxId:274},{bpxId:275},{bpxId:276},{bpxId:277},{bpxId:278},{bpxId:279},{bpxId:280},{bpxId:281},{bpxId:282},{bpxId:283},{bpxId:284},{bpxId:285},{bpxId:286},{bpxId:287},{bpxId:288},{bpxId:289},{bpxId:290},{bpxId:291},{bpxId:292},{bpxId:293},{bpxId:294},{bpxId:295},{bpxId:296},{bpxId:297},{bpxId:298},{bpxId:299},{bpxId:300},{bpxId:301},{bpxId:302},{bpxId:303},{bpxId:304},{bpxId:305},{bpxId:306},{bpxId:307},{bpxId:308},{bpxId:309},{bpxId:310},{bpxId:311},{bpxId:312},{bpxId:313},{bpxId:314},{bpxId:315},{bpxId:316},{bpxId:317},{bpxId:318},{bpxId:319},{bpxId:320},{bpxId:321},{bpxId:322},{bpxId:323},{bpxId:324},{bpxId:325},{bpxId:326},{bpxId:327},{bpxId:328},{bpxId:329},{bpxId:330},{bpxId:331},{bpxId:332},{bpxId:333},{bpxId:334},{bpxId:335},{bpxId:336},{bpxId:337},{bpxId:338},{bpxId:339},{bpxId:340},{bpxId:341},{bpxId:342},{bpxId:343},{bpxId:344},{bpxId:345},{bpxId:346},{bpxId:347},{bpxId:348},{bpxId:349},{bpxId:350},{bpxId:351},{bpxId:352},{bpxId:353},{bpxId:736},{bpxId:737},{bpxId:738},{bpxId:739},{bpxId:740},{bpxId:741},{bpxId:742},{bpxId:743},{bpxId:744},{bpxId:745},{bpxId:746},{bpxId:748},{bpxId:749},{bpxId:750},{bpxId:751},{bpxId:752},{bpxId:753},{bpxId:754},{bpxId:755},{bpxId:770},{bpxId:788},{bpxId:790},{bpxId:780},{bpxId:785},{bpxId:781},{bpxId:782},{bpxId:783},{bpxId:787},{bpxId:766},{bpxId:762},{bpxId:769},{bpxId:778},{bpxId:761},{bpxId:792},{bpxId:789},{bpxId:735},{bpxId:764},{bpxId:791},{bpxId:763},{bpxId:771},{bpxId:767},{bpxId:784},{bpxId:768},{bpxId:747},{bpxId:786},{bpxId:779},{bpxId:833}];

const teamLinks=[{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:2},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:11},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:91},{parentBpxTeamId:1,childBpxTeamId:270},{parentBpxTeamId:2,childBpxTeamId:3},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:4},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:5},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:6},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:7},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:8},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:9},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:10},{parentBpxTeamId:3,childBpxTeamId:92},{parentBpxTeamId:11,childBpxTeamId:12},{parentBpxTeamId:12,childBpxTeamId:13},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:15},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:24},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:38},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:54},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:62},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:69},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:73},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:76},{parentBpxTeamId:14,childBpxTeamId:88},{parentBpxTeamId:15,childBpxTeamId:16},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:17},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:18},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:19},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:20},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:21},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:22},{parentBpxTeamId:16,childBpxTeamId:23},{parentBpxTeamId:24,childBpxTeamId:25},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:26},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:27},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:28},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:29},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:30},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:31},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:32},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:33},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:34},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:35},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:36},{parentBpxTeamId:25,childBpxTeamId:37},{parentBpxTeamId:38,childBpxTeamId:39},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:40},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:41},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:42},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:43},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:44},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:45},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:46},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:47},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:48},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:49},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:50},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:51},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:52},{parentBpxTeamId:39,childBpxTeamId:53},{parentBpxTeamId:54,childBpxTeamId:55},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:56},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:57},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:58},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:59},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:60},{parentBpxTeamId:55,childBpxTeamId:61},{parentBpxTeamId:62,childBpxTeamId:63},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:64},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:65},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:66},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:67},{parentBpxTeamId:63,childBpxTeamId:68},{parentBpxTeamId:69,childBpxTeamId:70},{parentBpxTeamId:69,childBpxTeamId:71},{parentBpxTeamId:71,childBpxTeamId:72},{parentBpxTeamId:73,childBpxTeamId:74},{parentBpxTeamId:74,childBpxTeamId:75},{parentBpxTeamId:76,childBpxTeamId:77},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:78},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:79},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:80},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:81},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:82},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:83},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:84},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:85},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:86},{parentBpxTeamId:77,childBpxTeamId:87},{parentBpxTeamId:88,childBpxTeamId:89},{parentBpxTeamId:89,childBpxTeamId:90},{parentBpxTeamId:91,childBpxTeamId:3},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:94},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:97},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:100},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:103},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:104},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:106},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:109},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:112},{parentBpxTeamId:93,childBpxTeamId:115},{parentBpxTeamId:94,childBpxTeamId:95},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:96},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:98},{parentBpxTeamId:95,childBpxTeamId:99},{parentBpxTeamId:97,childBpxTeamId:95},{parentBpxTeamId:100,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:101,childBpxTeamId:102},{parentBpxTeamId:101,childBpxTeamId:105},{parentBpxTeamId:103,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:104,childBpxTeamId:101},{parentBpxTeamId:106,childBpxTeamId:107},{parentBpxTeamId:107,childBpxTeamId:108},{parentBpxTeamId:109,childBpxTeamId:110},{parentBpxTeamId:110,childBpxTeamId:111},{parentBpxTeamId:112,childBpxTeamId:113},{parentBpxTeamId:113,childBpxTeamId:114},{parentBpxTeamId:115,childBpxTeamId:116},{parentBpxTeamId:116,childBpxTeamId:117},{parentBpxTeamId:118,childBpxTeamId:119},{parentBpxTeamId:119,childBpxTeamId:120},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:122},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:139},{parentBpxTeamId:121,childBpxTeamId:144},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:123},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:125},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:127},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:129},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:131},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:133},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:135},{parentBpxTeamId:122,childBpxTeamId:137},{parentBpxTeamId:123,childBpxTeamId:124},{parentBpxTeamId:125,childBpxTeamId:126},{parentBpxTeamId:127,childBpxTeamId:128},{parentBpxTeamId:129,childBpxTeamId:130},{parentBpxTeamId:131,childBpxTeamId:132},{parentBpxTeamId:133,childBpxTeamId:134},{parentBpxTeamId:135,childBpxTeamId:136},{parentBpxTeamId:137,childBpxTeamId:138},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:140},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:141},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:142},{parentBpxTeamId:139,childBpxTeamId:143},{parentBpxTeamId:144,childBpxTeamId:145},{parentBpxTeamId:144,childBpxTeamId:146},{parentBpxTeamId:147,childBpxTeamId:148},{parentBpxTeamId:149,childBpxTeamId:150},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:154},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:156},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:158},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:160},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:162},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:164},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:166},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:168},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:170},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:172},{parentBpxTeamId:151,childBpxTeamId:174},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:153},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:155},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:157},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:159},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:161},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:163},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:165},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:167},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:169},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:171},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:173},{parentBpxTeamId:152,childBpxTeamId:175},{parentBpxTeamId:154,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:156,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:158,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:160,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:162,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:164,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:166,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:168,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:170,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:172,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:174,childBpxTeamId:152},{parentBpxTeamId:176,childBpxTeamId:177},{parentBpxTeamId:177,childBpxTeamId:178},{parentBpxTeamId:177,childBpxTeamId:768},{parentBpxTeamId:178,childBpxTeamId:179},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:181},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:183},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:185},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:187},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:189},{parentBpxTeamId:180,childBpxTeamId:191},{parentBpxTeamId:181,childBpxTeamId:182},{parentBpxTeamId:183,childBpxTeamId:184},{parentBpxTeamId:185,childBpxTeamId:186},{parentBpxTeamId:187,childBpxTeamId:188},{parentBpxTeamId:189,childBpxTeamId:190},{parentBpxTeamId:191,childBpxTeamId:192},{parentBpxTeamId:193,childBpxTeamId:194},{parentBpxTeamId:193,childBpxTeamId:197},{parentBpxTeamId:194,childBpxTeamId:195},{parentBpxTeamId:195,childBpxTeamId:196},{parentBpxTeamId:197,childBpxTeamId:198},{parentBpxTeamId:198,childBpxTeamId:199},{parentBpxTeamId:200,childBpxTeamId:201},{parentBpxTeamId:200,childBpxTeamId:204},{parentBpxTeamId:201,childBpxTeamId:202},{parentBpxTeamId:202,childBpxTeamId:203},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:205},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:207},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:209},{parentBpxTeamId:204,childBpxTeamId:210},{parentBpxTeamId:205,childBpxTeamId:206},{parentBpxTeamId:207,childBpxTeamId:208},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:212},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:215},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:217},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:219},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:221},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:223},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:226},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:228},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:230},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:232},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:234},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:236},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:238},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:240},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:242},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:244},{parentBpxTeamId:211,childBpxTeamId:246},{parentBpxTeamId:212,childBpxTeamId:213},{parentBpxTeamId:213,childBpxTeamId:214},{parentBpxTeamId:215,childBpxTeamId:216},{parentBpxTeamId:217,childBpxTeamId:218},{parentBpxTeamId:219,childBpxTeamId:220},{parentBpxTeamId:221,childBpxTeamId:222},{parentBpxTeamId:223,childBpxTeamId:224},{parentBpxTeamId:223,childBpxTeamId:225},{parentBpxTeamId:226,childBpxTeamId:227},{parentBpxTeamId:228,childBpxTeamId:229},{parentBpxTeamId:230,childBpxTeamId:231},{parentBpxTeamId:232,childBpxTeamId:233},{parentBpxTeamId:234,childBpxTeamId:235},{parentBpxTeamId:236,childBpxTeamId:237},{parentBpxTeamId:238,childBpxTeamId:239},{parentBpxTeamId:240,childBpxTeamId:241},{parentBpxTeamId:242,childBpxTeamId:243},{parentBpxTeamId:244,childBpxTeamId:245},{parentBpxTeamId:246,childBpxTeamId:247},{parentBpxTeamId:248,childBpxTeamId:249},{parentBpxTeamId:249,childBpxTeamId:250},{parentBpxTeamId:249,childBpxTeamId:251},{parentBpxTeamId:252,childBpxTeamId:253},{parentBpxTeamId:253,childBpxTeamId:254},{parentBpxTeamId:255,childBpxTeamId:256},{parentBpxTeamId:255,childBpxTeamId:257},{parentBpxTeamId:263,childBpxTeamId:264},{parentBpxTeamId:264,childBpxTeamId:265},{parentBpxTeamId:266,childBpxTeamId:267},{parentBpxTeamId:267,childBpxTeamId:268},{parentBpxTeamId:270,childBpxTeamId:271},{parentBpxTeamId:271,childBpxTeamId:272},{parentBpxTeamId:273,childBpxTeamId:274},{parentBpxTeamId:274,childBpxTeamId:275},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:276},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:277},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:278},{parentBpxTeamId:275,childBpxTeamId:279},{parentBpxTeamId:280,childBpxTeamId:281},{parentBpxTeamId:281,childBpxTeamId:282},{parentBpxTeamId:283,childBpxTeamId:284},{parentBpxTeamId:284,childBpxTeamId:285},{parentBpxTeamId:286,childBpxTeamId:287},{parentBpxTeamId:287,childBpxTeamId:288},{parentBpxTeamId:289,childBpxTeamId:290},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:291},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:292},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:293},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:294},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:295},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:296},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:297},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:298},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:299},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:300},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:301},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:302},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:303},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:304},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:305},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:306},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:307},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:308},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:309},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:310},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:311},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:312},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:313},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:314},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:315},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:316},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:317},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:318},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:319},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:320},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:321},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:322},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:323},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:324},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:325},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:326},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:327},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:328},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:329},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:330},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:331},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:332},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:333},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:334},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:335},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:336},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:337},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:338},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:339},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:340},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:341},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:342},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:343},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:344},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:345},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:346},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:347},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:348},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:349},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:350},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:351},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:352},{parentBpxTeamId:290,childBpxTeamId:353},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:736},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:737},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:738},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:739},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:740},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:741},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:742},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:743},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:744},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:745},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:746},{parentBpxTeamId:735,childBpxTeamId:766},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:748},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:749},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:750},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:751},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:752},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:753},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:754},{parentBpxTeamId:747,childBpxTeamId:755},{parentBpxTeamId:761,childBpxTeamId:762},{parentBpxTeamId:762,childBpxTeamId:763},{parentBpxTeamId:762,childBpxTeamId:764},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:747},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:778},{parentBpxTeamId:767,childBpxTeamId:789},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:769},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:770},{parentBpxTeamId:768,childBpxTeamId:771},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:779},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:780},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:781},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:782},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:783},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:784},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:785},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:786},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:787},{parentBpxTeamId:778,childBpxTeamId:788},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:790},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:791},{parentBpxTeamId:789,childBpxTeamId:792}];
 
const parents = new Map(teams.map(team => [team.bpxId, { ...team, children: [] }]));
const lut = new Map(parents);

teamLinks.forEach(({ parentBpxTeamId, childBpxTeamId }) => {
  lut.get(parentBpxTeamId).children.push(lut.get(childBpxTeamId));
  parents.delete(childBpxTeamId);
});

const hierarchies = Array.from(parents.values());

console.log(hierarchies);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very neat but I gave the answer to Nina as it doesn't leave team duplicates when moving them into the hierarchy

Comment: @Dominic fixed.

Comment: Nice one! Marking as correct since this is slightly more performant and you have fewer points and answered first

Answer (score 1):

You could take an objkect for the relations and render only parents who are not childrens.

```js
var teams = [{ bpxId: 1 }, { bpxId: 2 }, { bpxId: 3 }, { bpxId: 4 }, { bpxId: 5 }, { bpxId: 6 }, { bpxId: 7 }, { bpxId: 8 }, { bpxId: 9 }, { bpxId: 10 }, { bpxId: 11 }, { bpxId: 12 }, { bpxId: 13 }, { bpxId: 14 }, { bpxId: 15 }, { bpxId: 16 }, { bpxId: 17 }, { bpxId: 18 }, { bpxId: 19 }, { bpxId: 20 }, { bpxId: 21 }, { bpxId: 22 }, { bpxId: 23 }, { bpxId: 24 }, { bpxId: 25 }, { bpxId: 26 }, { bpxId: 27 }, { bpxId: 28 }, { bpxId: 29 }, { bpxId: 30 }, { bpxId: 31 }, { bpxId: 32 }, { bpxId: 33 }, { bpxId: 34 }, { bpxId: 35 }, { bpxId: 36 }, { bpxId: 37 }, { bpxId: 38 }, { bpxId: 39 }, { bpxId: 40 }, { bpxId: 41 }, { bpxId: 42 }, { bpxId: 43 }, { bpxId: 44 }, { bpxId: 45 }, { bpxId: 46 }, { bpxId: 47 }, { bpxId: 48 }, { bpxId: 49 }, { bpxId: 50 }, { bpxId: 51 }, { bpxId: 52 }, { bpxId: 53 }, { bpxId: 54 }, { bpxId: 55 }, { bpxId: 56 }, { bpxId: 57 }, { bpxId: 58 }, { bpxId: 59 }, { bpxId: 60 }, { bpxId: 61 }, { bpxId: 62 }, { bpxId: 63 }, { bpxId: 64 }, { bpxId: 65 }, { bpxId: 66 }, { bpxId: 67 }, { bpxId: 68 }, { bpxId: 69 }, { bpxId: 70 }, { bpxId: 71 }, { bpxId: 72 }, { bpxId: 73 }, { bpxId: 74 }, { bpxId: 75 }, { bpxId: 76 }, { bpxId: 77 }, { bpxId: 78 }, { bpxId: 79 }, { bpxId: 80 }, { bpxId: 81 }, { bpxId: 82 }, { bpxId: 83 }, { bpxId: 84 }, { bpxId: 85 }, { bpxId: 86 }, { bpxId: 87 }, { bpxId: 88 }, { bpxId: 89 }, { bpxId: 90 }, { bpxId: 91 }, { bpxId: 92 }, { bpxId: 93 }, { bpxId: 94 }, { bpxId: 95 }, { bpxId: 96 }, { bpxId: 97 }, { bpxId: 98 }, { bpxId: 99 }, { bpxId: 100 }, { bpxId: 101 }, { bpxId: 102 }, { bpxId: 103 }, { bpxId: 104 }, { bpxId: 105 }, { bpxId: 106 }, { bpxId: 107 }, { bpxId: 108 }, { bpxId: 109 }, { bpxId: 110 }, { bpxId: 111 }, { bpxId: 112 }, { bpxId: 113 }, { bpxId: 114 }, { bpxId: 115 }, { bpxId: 116 }, { bpxId: 117 }, { bpxId: 118 }, { bpxId: 119 }, { bpxId: 120 }, { bpxId: 121 }, { bpxId: 122 }, { bpxId: 123 }, { bpxId: 124 }, { bpxId: 125 }, { bpxId: 126 }, { bpxId: 127 }, { bpxId: 128 }, { bpxId: 129 }, { bpxId: 130 }, { bpxId: 131 }, { bpxId: 132 }, { bpxId: 133 }, { bpxId: 134 }, { bpxId: 135 }, { bpxId: 136 }, { bpxId: 137 }, { bpxId: 138 }, { bpxId: 139 }, { bpxId: 140 }, { bpxId: 141 }, { bpxId: 142 }, { bpxId: 143 }, { bpxId: 144 }, { bpxId: 145 }, { bpxId: 146 }, { bpxId: 147 }, { bpxId: 148 }, { bpxId: 149 }, { bpxId: 150 }, { bpxId: 151 }, { bpxId: 152 }, { bpxId: 153 }, { bpxId: 154 }, { bpxId: 155 }, { bpxId: 156 }, { bpxId: 157 }, { bpxId: 158 }, { bpxId: 159 }, { bpxId: 160 }, { bpxId: 161 }, { bpxId: 162 }, { bpxId: 163 }, { bpxId: 164 }, { bpxId: 165 }, { bpxId: 166 }, { bpxId: 167 }, { bpxId: 168 }, { bpxId: 169 }, { bpxId: 170 }, { bpxId: 171 }, { bpxId: 172 }, { bpxId: 173 }, { bpxId: 174 }, { bpxId: 175 }, { bpxId: 176 }, { bpxId: 177 }, { bpxId: 178 }, { bpxId: 179 }, { bpxId: 180 }, { bpxId: 181 }, { bpxId: 182 }, { bpxId: 183 }, { bpxId: 184 }, { bpxId: 185 }, { bpxId: 186 }, { bpxId: 187 }, { bpxId: 188 }, { bpxId: 189 }, { bpxId: 190 }, { bpxId: 191 }, { bpxId: 192 }, { bpxId: 193 }, { bpxId: 194 }, { bpxId: 195 }, { bpxId: 196 }, { bpxId: 197 }, { bpxId: 198 }, { bpxId: 199 }, { bpxId: 200 }, { bpxId: 201 }, { bpxId: 202 }, { bpxId: 203 }, { bpxId: 204 }, { bpxId: 205 }, { bpxId: 206 }, { bpxId: 207 }, { bpxId: 208 }, { bpxId: 209 }, { bpxId: 210 }, { bpxId: 211 }, { bpxId: 212 }, { bpxId: 213 }, { bpxId: 214 }, { bpxId: 215 }, { bpxId: 216 }, { bpxId: 217 }, { bpxId: 218 }, { bpxId: 219 }, { bpxId: 220 }, { bpxId: 221 }, { bpxId: 222 }, { bpxId: 223 }, { bpxId: 224 }, { bpxId: 225 }, { bpxId: 226 }, { bpxId: 227 }, { bpxId: 228 }, { bpxId: 229 }, { bpxId: 230 }, { bpxId: 231 }, { bpxId: 232 }, { bpxId: 233 }, { bpxId: 234 }, { bpxId: 235 }, { bpxId: 236 }, { bpxId: 237 }, { bpxId: 238 }, { bpxId: 239 }, { bpxId: 240 }, { bpxId: 241 }, { bpxId: 242 }, { bpxId: 243 }, { bpxId: 244 }, { bpxId: 245 }, { bpxId: 246 }, { bpxId: 247 }, { bpxId: 248 }, { bpxId: 249 }, { bpxId: 250 }, { bpxId: 251 }, { bpxId: 252 }, { bpxId: 253 }, { bpxId: 254 }, { bpxId: 255 }, { bpxId: 256 }, { bpxId: 257 }, { bpxId: 258 }, { bpxId: 259 }, { bpxId: 260 }, { bpxId: 261 }, { bpxId: 262 }, { bpxId: 263 }, { bpxId: 264 }, { bpxId: 265 }, { bpxId: 266 }, { bpxId: 267 }, { bpxId: 268 }, { bpxId: 269 }, { bpxId: 270 }, { bpxId: 271 }, { bpxId: 272 }, { bpxId: 273 }, { bpxId: 274 }, { bpxId: 275 }, { bpxId: 276 }, { bpxId: 277 }, { bpxId: 278 }, { bpxId: 279 }, { bpxId: 280 }, { bpxId: 281 }, { bpxId: 282 }, { bpxId: 283 }, { bpxId: 284 }, { bpxId: 285 }, { bpxId: 286 }, { bpxId: 287 }, { bpxId: 288 }, { bpxId: 289 }, { bpxId: 290 }, { bpxId: 291 }, { bpxId: 292 }, { bpxId: 293 }, { bpxId: 294 }, { bpxId: 295 }, { bpxId: 296 }, { bpxId: 297 }, { bpxId: 298 }, { bpxId: 299 }, { bpxId: 300 }, { bpxId: 301 }, { bpxId: 302 }, { bpxId: 303 }, { bpxId: 304 }, { bpxId: 305 }, { bpxId: 306 }, { bpxId: 307 }, { bpxId: 308 }, { bpxId: 309 }, { bpxId: 310 }, { bpxId: 311 }, { bpxId: 312 }, { bpxId: 313 }, { bpxId: 314 }, { bpxId: 315 }, { bpxId: 316 }, { bpxId: 317 }, { bpxId: 318 }, { bpxId: 319 }, { bpxId: 320 }, { bpxId: 321 }, { bpxId: 322 }, { bpxId: 323 }, { bpxId: 324 }, { bpxId: 325 }, { bpxId: 326 }, { bpxId: 327 }, { bpxId: 328 }, { bpxId: 329 }, { bpxId: 330 }, { bpxId: 331 }, { bpxId: 332 }, { bpxId: 333 }, { bpxId: 334 }, { bpxId: 335 }, { bpxId: 336 }, { bpxId: 337 }, { bpxId: 338 }, { bpxId: 339 }, { bpxId: 340 }, { bpxId: 341 }, { bpxId: 342 }, { bpxId: 343 }, { bpxId: 344 }, { bpxId: 345 }, { bpxId: 346 }, { bpxId: 347 }, { bpxId: 348 }, { bpxId: 349 }, { bpxId: 350 }, { bpxId: 351 }, { bpxId: 352 }, { bpxId: 353 }, { bpxId: 736 }, { bpxId: 737 }, { bpxId: 738 }, { bpxId: 739 }, { bpxId: 740 }, { bpxId: 741 }, { bpxId: 742 }, { bpxId: 743 }, { bpxId: 744 }, { bpxId: 745 }, { bpxId: 746 }, { bpxId: 748 }, { bpxId: 749 }, { bpxId: 750 }, { bpxId: 751 }, { bpxId: 752 }, { bpxId: 753 }, { bpxId: 754 }, { bpxId: 755 }, { bpxId: 770 }, { bpxId: 788 }, { bpxId: 790 }, { bpxId: 780 }, { bpxId: 785 }, { bpxId: 781 }, { bpxId: 782 }, { bpxId: 783 }, { bpxId: 787 }, { bpxId: 766 }, { bpxId: 762 }, { bpxId: 769 }, { bpxId: 778 }, { bpxId: 761 }, { bpxId: 792 }, { bpxId: 789 }, { bpxId: 735 }, { bpxId: 764 }, { bpxId: 791 }, { bpxId: 763 }, { bpxId: 771 }, { bpxId: 767 }, { bpxId: 784 }, { bpxId: 768 }, { bpxId: 747 }, { bpxId: 786 }, { bpxId: 779 }, { bpxId: 833 }],
    teamLinks = [{ parentBpxTeamId: 1, childBpxTeamId: 2 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 1, childBpxTeamId: 11 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 1, childBpxTeamId: 91 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 1, childBpxTeamId: 270 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 2, childBpxTeamId: 3 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 4 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 5 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 6 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 7 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 8 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 9 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 10 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 3, childBpxTeamId: 92 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 11, childBpxTeamId: 12 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 12, childBpxTeamId: 13 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 15 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 24 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 38 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 54 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 62 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 69 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 73 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 76 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 14, childBpxTeamId: 88 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 15, childBpxTeamId: 16 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 17 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 18 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 19 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 20 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 21 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 22 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 16, childBpxTeamId: 23 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 24, childBpxTeamId: 25 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 26 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 27 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 28 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 29 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 30 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 31 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 32 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 33 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 34 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 35 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 36 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 25, childBpxTeamId: 37 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 38, childBpxTeamId: 39 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 40 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 41 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 42 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 43 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 44 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 45 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 46 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 47 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 48 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 49 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 50 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 51 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 52 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 39, childBpxTeamId: 53 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 54, childBpxTeamId: 55 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 56 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 57 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 58 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 59 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 60 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 55, childBpxTeamId: 61 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 62, childBpxTeamId: 63 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 63, childBpxTeamId: 64 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 63, childBpxTeamId: 65 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 63, childBpxTeamId: 66 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 63, childBpxTeamId: 67 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 63, childBpxTeamId: 68 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 69, childBpxTeamId: 70 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 69, childBpxTeamId: 71 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 71, childBpxTeamId: 72 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 73, childBpxTeamId: 74 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 74, childBpxTeamId: 75 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 76, childBpxTeamId: 77 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 78 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 79 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 80 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 81 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 82 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 83 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 84 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 85 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 86 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 77, childBpxTeamId: 87 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 88, childBpxTeamId: 89 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 89, childBpxTeamId: 90 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 91, childBpxTeamId: 3 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 94 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 97 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 100 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 103 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 104 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 106 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 109 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 112 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 93, childBpxTeamId: 115 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 94, childBpxTeamId: 95 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 95, childBpxTeamId: 96 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 95, childBpxTeamId: 98 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 95, childBpxTeamId: 99 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 97, childBpxTeamId: 95 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 100, childBpxTeamId: 101 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 101, childBpxTeamId: 102 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 101, childBpxTeamId: 105 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 103, childBpxTeamId: 101 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 104, childBpxTeamId: 101 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 106, childBpxTeamId: 107 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 107, childBpxTeamId: 108 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 109, childBpxTeamId: 110 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 110, childBpxTeamId: 111 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 112, childBpxTeamId: 113 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 113, childBpxTeamId: 114 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 115, childBpxTeamId: 116 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 116, childBpxTeamId: 117 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 118, childBpxTeamId: 119 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 119, childBpxTeamId: 120 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 121, childBpxTeamId: 122 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 121, childBpxTeamId: 139 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 121, childBpxTeamId: 144 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 123 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 125 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 127 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 129 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 131 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 133 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 135 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 122, childBpxTeamId: 137 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 123, childBpxTeamId: 124 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 125, childBpxTeamId: 126 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 127, childBpxTeamId: 128 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 129, childBpxTeamId: 130 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 131, childBpxTeamId: 132 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 133, childBpxTeamId: 134 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 135, childBpxTeamId: 136 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 137, childBpxTeamId: 138 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 139, childBpxTeamId: 140 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 139, childBpxTeamId: 141 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 139, childBpxTeamId: 142 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 139, childBpxTeamId: 143 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 144, childBpxTeamId: 145 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 144, childBpxTeamId: 146 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 147, childBpxTeamId: 148 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 149, childBpxTeamId: 150 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 154 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 156 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 158 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 160 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 162 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 164 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 166 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 168 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 170 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 172 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 151, childBpxTeamId: 174 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 153 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 155 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 157 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 159 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 161 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 163 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 165 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 167 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 169 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 171 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 173 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 152, childBpxTeamId: 175 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 154, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 156, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 158, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 160, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 162, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 164, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 166, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 168, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 170, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 172, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 174, childBpxTeamId: 152 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 176, childBpxTeamId: 177 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 177, childBpxTeamId: 178 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 177, childBpxTeamId: 768 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 178, childBpxTeamId: 179 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 181 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 183 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 185 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 187 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 189 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 180, childBpxTeamId: 191 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 181, childBpxTeamId: 182 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 183, childBpxTeamId: 184 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 185, childBpxTeamId: 186 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 187, childBpxTeamId: 188 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 189, childBpxTeamId: 190 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 191, childBpxTeamId: 192 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 193, childBpxTeamId: 194 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 193, childBpxTeamId: 197 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 194, childBpxTeamId: 195 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 195, childBpxTeamId: 196 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 197, childBpxTeamId: 198 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 198, childBpxTeamId: 199 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 200, childBpxTeamId: 201 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 200, childBpxTeamId: 204 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 201, childBpxTeamId: 202 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 202, childBpxTeamId: 203 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 204, childBpxTeamId: 205 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 204, childBpxTeamId: 207 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 204, childBpxTeamId: 209 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 204, childBpxTeamId: 210 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 205, childBpxTeamId: 206 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 207, childBpxTeamId: 208 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 212 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 215 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 217 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 219 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 221 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 223 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 226 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 228 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 230 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 232 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 234 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 236 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 238 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 240 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 242 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 244 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 211, childBpxTeamId: 246 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 212, childBpxTeamId: 213 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 213, childBpxTeamId: 214 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 215, childBpxTeamId: 216 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 217, childBpxTeamId: 218 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 219, childBpxTeamId: 220 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 221, childBpxTeamId: 222 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 223, childBpxTeamId: 224 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 223, childBpxTeamId: 225 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 226, childBpxTeamId: 227 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 228, childBpxTeamId: 229 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 230, childBpxTeamId: 231 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 232, childBpxTeamId: 233 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 234, childBpxTeamId: 235 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 236, childBpxTeamId: 237 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 238, childBpxTeamId: 239 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 240, childBpxTeamId: 241 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 242, childBpxTeamId: 243 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 244, childBpxTeamId: 245 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 246, childBpxTeamId: 247 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 248, childBpxTeamId: 249 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 249, childBpxTeamId: 250 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 249, childBpxTeamId: 251 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 252, childBpxTeamId: 253 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 253, childBpxTeamId: 254 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 255, childBpxTeamId: 256 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 255, childBpxTeamId: 257 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 263, childBpxTeamId: 264 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 264, childBpxTeamId: 265 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 266, childBpxTeamId: 267 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 267, childBpxTeamId: 268 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 270, childBpxTeamId: 271 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 271, childBpxTeamId: 272 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 273, childBpxTeamId: 274 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 274, childBpxTeamId: 275 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 275, childBpxTeamId: 276 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 275, childBpxTeamId: 277 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 275, childBpxTeamId: 278 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 275, childBpxTeamId: 279 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 280, childBpxTeamId: 281 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 281, childBpxTeamId: 282 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 283, childBpxTeamId: 284 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 284, childBpxTeamId: 285 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 286, childBpxTeamId: 287 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 287, childBpxTeamId: 288 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 289, childBpxTeamId: 290 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 291 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 292 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 293 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 294 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 295 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 296 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 297 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 298 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 299 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 300 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 301 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 302 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 303 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 304 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 305 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 306 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 307 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 308 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 309 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 310 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 311 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 312 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 313 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 314 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 315 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 316 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 317 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 318 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 319 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 320 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 321 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 322 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 323 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 324 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 325 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 326 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 327 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 328 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 329 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 330 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 331 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 332 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 333 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 334 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 335 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 336 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 337 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 338 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 339 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 340 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 341 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 342 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 343 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 344 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 345 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 346 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 347 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 348 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 349 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 350 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 351 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 352 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 290, childBpxTeamId: 353 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 736 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 737 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 738 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 739 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 740 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 741 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 742 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 743 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 744 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 745 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 746 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 735, childBpxTeamId: 766 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 748 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 749 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 750 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 751 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 752 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 753 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 754 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 747, childBpxTeamId: 755 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 761, childBpxTeamId: 762 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 762, childBpxTeamId: 763 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 762, childBpxTeamId: 764 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 767, childBpxTeamId: 747 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 767, childBpxTeamId: 778 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 767, childBpxTeamId: 789 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 768, childBpxTeamId: 769 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 768, childBpxTeamId: 770 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 768, childBpxTeamId: 771 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 779 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 780 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 781 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 782 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 783 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 784 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 785 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 786 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 787 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 778, childBpxTeamId: 788 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 789, childBpxTeamId: 790 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 789, childBpxTeamId: 791 }, { parentBpxTeamId: 789, childBpxTeamId: 792 }],
    parents = new Set,
    relation = {},
    result;


teams.forEach(o => {
    relation[o.bpxId] = Object.assign({}, o);
    parents.add(o.bpxId);
});

teamLinks.forEach(({ parentBpxTeamId: parent, childBpxTeamId: id }) => {
    (relation[parent].children = relation[parent].children || []).push(relation[id]);
    parents.delete(id);
});

result = Array.from(parents, id => relation[id]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great now I just need to read through and understand this cleverness

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand that the `teamLinks` array describes parent-child relations between the `teams`. A two step process would be to index the teams so they can be accessed quickly by id, then iterate the teamLinks, making assignments between the indexed teams.

This mini-example assumes you wish to modify the original team objects to include their children.  The same could also be done on a copy of each team object in order to preserve the original.

```js
const teams = [{
  bpxId: 1
}, {
  bpxId: 2
}, {
  bpxId: 3
}, {
  bpxId: 4
}]
const teamLinks = [{
  parentBpxTeamId: 1,
  childBpxTeamId: 2
}, {
  parentBpxTeamId: 1,
  childBpxTeamId: 3
}, {
  parentBpxTeamId: 3,
  childBpxTeamId: 4
}];


let indexedTeams = {};

// build an index of the teams for quick access
// give each team a children array
teams.forEach(team => {
  team.children = []
  indexedTeams[team.bpxId] = team;
});

// make children assignments from team links
teamLinks.forEach(link => {
    let parent = indexedTeams[link.parentBpxTeamId];
    let child = indexedTeams[link.childBpxTeamId];
    parent.children.push(child);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(teams, null, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer but using the dataset in the question I end up with an object with 833 items which isn't correct